# Eclipse C++ Run blocked by Docker config with message "Docker Connection is missing or invalid"

Tags: eclipse, docker

[this is the config popup "Docker Connection is missing or invalid"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG1Wq.png)

*Basic description:*

I have been having some troubles with Eclipse at every turn, it seems. After I build my code(with no issues), I run the program, and a config popup tells me that I'm missing a docker connection... to be entirely truthful, I'm not even that sure what a docker is/does. To my knowledge, I am not using a docker in any way.

---

**sidenotes**

-this happens for any program I attempt to run (hello world or anything)
-I am not experienced with Eclipse, but I have run code without this issue

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that this was an issue with the launch configs of my code; Eclipse had changed up my launch configs to accommodate a VM I had on my system.